# HAProxy - rewrite path from domain prefix

Tags: url-rewriting, dns, haproxy, prefix

I would like to rewrite path from the domain prefix. With two cases :

1. https://prefix.domain.com/path -> https://prefix.domain.com/path/#/prefix
2. https://prefix.domain.com/path1 -> https://prefix.domain.com/path1/#/prefix/home

I try to rewrite the path with this config. But I can not extract prefix from domain in reqirep. I think that reqrep is only for GET /XXXX HTTP/1.1 string, not full URL.

```
    acl match path_end -i /path
    acl match1 path_end -i /path1
    use_backend traefik_path if match
    use_backend traefik_path1 if match1
    default_backend traefik_path

    backend traefik_path
      reqirep ^([^\ ]*\ /)path \1/path/#/??
      balance roundrobin
      server traefik 127.0.0.1:8000 check
    backend traefik_path1
      reqirep ^([^\ ]*\ /)path1 \1/path1/#/??/home
      balance roundrobin
      server traefik 127.0.0.1:8000 check
```

Comment: I have similar problem here http://serverfault.com/questions/815484/how-to-rewrite-url-with-subdomain-in-haproxy

Comment: The part after # is a client part of the url, that means browser never send it to server.  So I think you should try redirect instead of rewrite